# Magento call product page directly through menu click & display first product of the category by default

Tags: magento, drop-down-menu

I need to display product view page directly without having the category page when click on top header menu. The details are as :

1. When user clicks on menu it redirects to the product view page.
2. It first shows the default first item of the product from category.

Thanks in advance & i need it very quick please help!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the first product of a category :

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addCategoryFilter($category)->getFirstItem();
```

Then you have 2 ways to proceed :

1°) Rewrite the Navigation Block to replace the getCategoryUrl() function to handle this

```
public function getCategoryUrl($category)
{
    if ($category instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Category) {
        $cat = $category;
    } else {
        $cat  = $this->_getCategoryInstance()
            ->setData($category->getData());
    }

    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addCategoryFilter($cat)->getFirstItem();
    return $_product->getProductUrl();
}
```

2°) Less clean, rewrite the Controller (catalog/category/view) to catch the first product and redirect to catalog/product/view or adapt the behaviour to fit the product view controller. This is not clean, but allow to see the product page on the catalog url :

With the first method, you'll go directly to www.yoursite.com/product.html with the second one you can see the product on www.yoursite.com/category.html (and as it's not the real product page you can add some static block or so on to allow changing product.)

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply but if you could have a look at this as i want to display the products on here : http://localhost/diamonds/index.php/engagement-rings/classic-solitaire.html

As it is now showing here :http://localhost/diamonds/index.php/engagement-rings/classic-solitaire/htc-touch-diamond.html

with the dafault display of first product so basically it is list.phtml that is going to render view.phtml in itself with default product that is first one from the category products.

Thanks for your help much appreciated.

Comment: To sum up, you want the first product shown but the url of the page should be the url of the category not the real url of the product showing right ?

Comment: Ok thanks i find it right thanks for your help thank u very much. You could now see the url here as : http://zstylish.in/diamonds/index.php/ 
RThis is the thing which i was searching for & you helped me a lot thank u very much.